# iOS and corona view landscape issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, coronasdk

I am trying to integrate corona (game platform) with iOS project using corona cards. Below is what I am trying to achieve:

- Programmatically load corona view controller (ViewController.m/ViewController.h) from AppDelegate.m
- Force landscape mode for corona view controller

Below is the code:

***AppDelegate.m***

```html
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

***ViewController.m***

```html
@interface ViewController ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) CoronaViewController *coronaController;
@end

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  _coronaController = [[CoronaViewController alloc] init];
  [self addChildViewController:_coronaController];
  
  CoronaView *coronaView = (CoronaView *)_coronaController.view;
  coronaView.frame = self.view.frame;
  
  [self.view addSubview:coronaView];
  [coronaView run];
}
```

Here's the screenshot of how it looks:

- Portrait mode: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBS8D.jpg)
- Landscape mode: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwXzJ.jpg)

The issue is that when I go to landscape, the image should take up the entire screen but instead it just shows partial image.

*** UPDATE ***
I was able to get this working by doing the following:

```html
CGRect appFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
_coronaView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -162, appFrame.size.height, appFrame.size.width);
[self.view addSubview:_coronaView];
[_coronaView setNeedsLayout];
```

However, I am not sure why I had to set my y to -162. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it resolves your issue

Comment: I tried your approach and the image looks stretch. Here's the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/X3IgI

Comment: is your `image` inside `UIImageView`? If so, set `imageView.contentMode =     UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

Comment: The image is actually being served from corona

Comment: The image is stretched because the content mode is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`. So, we can't do anything about it if we can't control it. Not taking entire screen issue is resolved right?

Comment: Nope. It is not taking entire screen. Check this image out: https://imgur.com/a/YJVpF - Here's the landscape image that does not get stretched but does not fill the entire screen.

Comment: Can you please try setting `coronaView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` and check once.

Comment: I did and no changes. :(

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you go to `Landscape mode` from `Portrait mode`, the width and height of screen changes. So, `coronaView.frame.size.width != [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width` when shifted from `Portrait` to `Landscape`

To resolve these issues, it's better to use `AutoLayout` for setting frame or setting frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in `ViewController`s,

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    CoronaView *coronaView = (CoronaView *)_coronaController.view;
    coronaView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _coronaController = [[CoronaViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:_coronaController];

    CoronaView *coronaView = (CoronaView *)_coronaController.view;
    [self.view addSubview:coronaView];

    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:coronaView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:coronaView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:coronaView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:coronaView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];
   [self.view addConstraints:@[constraint1, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4]];
}
```